# How to pass name of another activity as a parameter to a method in another activity

Tags: android, class, android-activity, type-conversion

So I am trying to use ActivityOptionsCompat here

```
    ActivityOptionsCompat options = 
        ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(NoticeViewer.class,
        v,   // The view which starts the transition
        transitionName    // The transitionName of the view we’re transitioning to
        );
```

The first argument is supposed to be an Activity object, which I'm trying to supply through the relevant class file, but I get the following type conversion error -

```
Error:(194, 54) error: no suitable method found for makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Class<NoticeViewer>,View,String)
method ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity,View,String) is not applicable
(actual argument Class<NoticeViewer> cannot be converted to Activity by method invocation conversion)
method ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity,Pair<View,String>...) is not applicable
(actual argument Class<NoticeViewer> cannot be converted to Activity by method invocation conversion)
```

I'm missing something really simple, but what is it?

Comment: `NoticeViewer.class` This is a Class object not an `Activity` object. You can use `NoticeViewer.this` to return the instance of the class.

Comment: `NoticeViewer.this` throws a "not an enclosing class error"

Comment: Yes, you should pass it the current activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NoticeViewer.this` instead of `NoticeViewer.class` to pass current Activity Context as first parameter :

```
ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(NoticeBoard.this,...)
```

Comment: `NoticeViewer` is not my current activity. It is `NoticeBoard.class`. So when I click on a list item in `NoticeBoard`, it takes me to `NoticeViewer`.

Comment: By using NoticeViewer.this, I get a "not an enclosing class error"

Comment: @user3210476: then pass `NoticeBoard.this` instead of `NoticeViewer.this`

Comment: Oh okay. I thought I was supposed to pass the destination activity. Works. Thanks  ρяσѕρєя K